# Prevening svn checkout list to be shown in terminal

Tags: command-line, python, svn

I wrote a python code and at some point it checks out using `svn`. I don't want to see the outputs of `svn` on my terminal screen. I heard that to block this, I should use `/dev/bin` or something like that, but I don't know how could I do that and what should I do. Is there anyone to help me?

Comment: This question is answered here [41964](https://serverfault.com/questions/41964/how-can-i-hide-the-output-of-a-shell-application-in-linux)

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the output of `svn` command to [`/dev/null`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null) using:

```
svn <command> [options] [args] 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

`svn co -q URL` in most cases output nothing to stdout

Comment: Those "most cases" you can count them on the fingers.